# Quickly finding $\theta$ from $\sin\theta=\frac{3}{\sqrt{73}}$. (In particular, why can we say that $\theta<37^\circ$?)

Tags: trigonometry

> If it is given to you that
> $$\sin\theta = \frac{3}{\sqrt{73}}$$
> then how will you find this angle quickly?

So you can imagine that real diagram is like this

[image]

The thing is to find that angle $\theta$.

> Also, my teacher assumed it intuitively that $\theta$ is less than $37^\circ$. What is the way to do that?

Comment: Your teacher intuited that the angle is less than $37^\circ$ because $\sqrt{73}>\sqrt{25}=5$, and a 3-4-5 right-angled triangle has roughly $37^\circ$ opposite the $3$ side. In fact, it's rather easy to see that the angle is less than $30^\circ$, as $\sqrt{73}>\sqrt{36}=6$.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're evaluating $\arctan\tfrac38\approx20.56^\circ$, which needs a calculator, but $\arctan\tfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}=30^\circ$ is a tighter upper bound than your teacher requested. @Arthur obtained it another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can even safely assume it's under 30 degrees, way less than 30 in fact, since at 30 degrees, the opposing side reaches half of hypothenuse, and 3 is way less than $\frac{\sqrt{73}}{2}$, so your angle is below $30 ^ \circ$.